# Simplifying triple nested loop to avoid callback hell in android retrofit2 (via RxJava2?)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

## Context

Using android retrofit2, need to access deeply nested `name` strings to fetch and display their `Details` (where `Detail`s object has reference to the `Group` and `User` objects used to get the `Detail`).

The `JSON` consists of a list of `Group`s that each contain a list of `User`s that each contain a list of `name` `String`s which are captured in these models:

```
public class Group {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("users")
    public List<User> users;
}
public class User {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("detailNames")
    public List<String> detailNames;
}
public class Detail {
    // allow access to objects used to get detail
    public Group group;
    public User user;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("description")
    public String description;
}
```

The models are populated using the `UserApi`:

```
public interface UserApi {
    @GET("groups")
    Call<List<Group>> getGroups();

    @GET("groups/{group_id}/users/{user_id}/details/{detail_name}")
    Call<Detail> getDetail(
            @Path("group_id") String groupId,
            @Path("user_id") String userId,
            @Path("detail_name") String detailName
    );
}
```

## Aim

The aim is to use a given `UserApi` to make and parse requests to display a `Dialog`  in the format of:

```
Group1 (expandable heading)
    User1 (expandable heading)
        Detail1 (checkbox)
        Detail2 (checkbox)
        ...
Group2 (expandable heading)
    User2 (expandable heading)
        Detail1 (checkbox)
        ...
    ...
...
```

## Problem

The problem is the current solution requests `Group`s and uses a triple nested `for` loop to access and fetch `Detail`s for each `name`:

```
private void fetchDetails(List<Group> groupList) {
    ArrayList<Group> groups = (ArrayList<Group>) groupList;
    if (groups != null && groups.size() > 0) {
        for (Group group : groups) {
            for (User user: group.users) {
                for (String detailName : user.detailNames) {
                    fetchDetail(group, user, detailName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is worsened since the triple loop makes a request for each `name`, and is done within the `getGroups` `onResponse` callback, which seems unreadable/unmaintainable:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mUserApi = UserApiClient.getApi();
    fetchGroups();
}
private void fetchGroups() {
    Callback<List<Group>> groupsCall = new Callback<List<Group>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Group>> call, Response<List<Group>> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            switch (statusCode) {
                case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                    List<Group> groups = response.body();
                    fetchDetails(groups);
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Group>> call, Throwable t) {}
    };
    mUserApi.getGroups().enqueue(groupsCall);
}
private void fetchDetail(final Group group, final User user, String detailName) {
    Callback<Detail> detailCallback= new Callback<Detail>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Detail> call, Response<Detail> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            switch (statusCode) {
                case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // display details in ListView
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Detail> call, Throwable t) {}
    };
    mUserApi.getDetail(group.id, user.id, detailName).enqueue(detailCallback);
}
```

An RxJava2 solution was suggested to avoid nesting callbacks like the above implementation, but was unfinished due to confusion regarding managing 3 layers of nesting to access the `names`:

```
Observable<List<Group>> groupCall =  mUserApi.getGroups();
groupCall.flatMapIterable(x -> x)
   .flatMap(group -> {
       Observable.fromIterable(group.users)
           .flatMap(user -> {
               Observable.fromIterable(user.detailNames)
                   .map(detailName -> {
                        mUserApi.getDetail(group.id, user.id, detailName)
                            .flatMap(detail -> {
                                detail.group = group;
                                detail.user = user;
                                return Observable.just(detail)
                            })
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Group>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}
                                @Override
                                public void onNext(List<Detail> value) {
                                    mDetails = (ArrayList<Detail>) value;
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {}
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {}
                            });
                   });
           }
   })
```

There have been some questions (e.g., [RxJava multiple loop with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403661/rxjava-multiple-loop-with-condition)) that deal with nesting in RxJava but still unsure how to apply these to the deeply nested `name`s.

## Question

Is it possible to use RxJava2 to avoid callback hell and simplify the triple `for` loop, is there another way, or should the solution resort to synchronous requests within `AsyncTask`/`AsyncTaskLoader`?

Comment: You can save yourself some nesting by suppressing the extra curly-braces that enclose the `map()` bodies. Also, the most interior `flatMap()` is really just a `map()`.

Comment: It looks like there isn't much improvement that can be made from what you already have. The problem is that the code needs to access `Group` and `User` inside the innermost loop. If you really wanted to get rid of the loop, one thing you can do is to create a wrapper object, and for each `nameDetail` you can bundle matching `user` and `group` together when passing it down the stream.

Comment: @SanlokLee sounds like a useful improvement, do you have an example?

Comment: I've added the api interface and overall aim to the question in case it helps reveal an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, I think what you already have is pretty much the simplest form you can get. But it seems you are interested in doing this without the loop so here's a couple of suggestions (but not necessarily better):

**Method 1: Container Classes**

If you are willing to create intermediate container classes that can hold group, user, detailname in a single object, you can do something like this:

First, create these container classes:

```
public class UserWithGroup {
    final Group group;
    final User user;

    public UserWithGroup(Group group, User user) {
        this.group = group;
        this.user = user;
    }
}

public class DetailWithUser {
    final Group group;
    final User user;
    final String detailName;

    public DetailWithUser(Group group, User user, String detailName) {
        this.group = group;
        this.user = user;
        this.detailName = detailName;
    }
}
```

Then your code with Java 8 Stream can be:

```
private void fetchDetails(List<Group> groupList) {
    groupList.stream()
            .flatMap(g -> g.users.stream().map(u -> new UserWithGroup(g, u)))
            .flatMap(ug -> ug.user.detailNames.stream().map(n -> new DetailWithUser(ug.group, ug.user, n)))
            .forEach(d -> fetchDetail(d.group, d.user, d.detailName));
}
```

Or with RxJava:

```
private void fetchDetails2(List<Group> groupList) {
    Observable.fromIterable(groupList)
            .flatMap(g -> Observable.fromIterable(g.users).map(u -> new UserWithGroup(g, u)))
            .flatMap(ug -> Observable.fromIterable(ug.user.detailNames).map(n -> new DetailWithUser(ug.group, ug.user, n)))
            .flatMap(d -> mUserApi.getDetail(d.group.id, d.user.id, d.detailName)
                    .map(detail -> {
                        detail.group = d.group;
                        detail.user = d.user;
                        return detail
                    }))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(detail -> {
                ...
            });
}
```

**Method2:**

`Android.util.Pair` a container class that can hold any two objects. If you use this instead of creating intermediate containers, and you are okay with it, the code can be further simplified.

Java 8 Stream and Pair:

```
private void fetchDetails3(List<Group> groupList) {
    groupList.stream()
            .flatMap(g -> g.users.stream().map(u -> Pair.create(g, u)))
            .flatMap(p -> p.second.detailNames.stream().map(n -> Pair.create(p, n)))
            .forEach(p -> fetchDetail(p.first.first, p.first.second, p.second));
}
```

RxJava and Pair:

```
private void fetchDetails4(List<Group> groupList) {
    Observable.fromIterable(groupList)
            .flatMap(g -> Observable.fromIterable(g.users).map(u -> Pair.create(g, u)))
            .flatMap(p -> Observable.fromIterable(p.second.detailNames).map(n -> Pair.create(p, n)))
            .flatMap(p -> fetchDetail2(p.first.first, p.first.second, p.second)
                    .map(detail -> {
                        detail.group = d.group;
                        detail.user = d.user;
                        return detail
                    }))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(detail -> {
                ...
            });
}
```

Comment: Excellent solutions, method 1 is elegant and what the RxJava solution was trying to do via `Detail`, so answers the question. Is there a reason for not using `forEach` in method 1 RxJava? Was unaware of method 2 but it seems less readable.

Comment: That's an interesting question. First of all, I did not know RxJava had `forEach` operator. I just did a quick research and found out `forEach` is almost identical to `subscribe` but it seems the `forEach` behavior is not as consistent as `subscribe`.

Comment: Going back to the topic, _Java 8 Stream_ is not asynchronous, and there is no concept of _time_. Your asynchronous server request happens inside `fetchDetail` method. Unlike `forEach` in Java Stream, `subscribe` in RxJava does not imply anything about synchronicity, as in the example asynchronous operations can be done without exiting the stream.

Comment: Good point regarding async. Was confused on the difference that in method 1, java8 has 2 `flatMap`s and 1 `forEach` whereas rxjava2 has 3 `flatMap`s.